# Необходимо сделать анимированный квадрат tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Приветствую и всех за одно с праздником.
Решаю вот такую задачку:
Исходно фигура имеет вид квадрата со стороной 400 пикселей. При запуске движения центры сторон начинают попиксельно сходиться к центру фигуры со скоростью 8 пик-селей/сек., превращая квадрат в крест X. Затем начинается обратное движение, и фигура возвращается к квадрату. Движение циклически повторяется. Запуск и остановка движения - радионабор.
Не могу только допереть как можно это движение реализовать, надеюсь хотя бы на подсказку.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('main')
root.geometry('600x800')
 
c = Canvas(width=600, height=800, bg='white')
c.place(x=0, y=0)
 
n = 8
  
def move():
    s=c.coords(l1)
    s1=c.coords(l3)
    s2=c.coords(l5)
    s3=c.coords(l7)
    if s[3] < 200:
        s[3] = s[3]+n
        c.coords(l1, 200,100,300,s[3])
        c.coords(l2, 300,s[3],400,100)
        print(s)
        print(s[3])
        c.after(0)

    if s1[2] > 300:
        s1[2] = s1[2]-n
        c.coords(l3, 400,100,s1[2],200)
        c.coords(l4, s1[2],200,400,300)
        c.after(0)

    if s2[3] > 200:
        s2[3] = s2[3]-n
        c.coords(l5, 400,300,300,s2[3])
        c.coords(l6, 300,s2[3],200,300)
        c.after(0)

    if s3[2] < 300:
        s3[2] = s3[2]+n
        c.coords(l7, 200,300,s3[2],200)
        c.coords(l8, s3[2],200,200,100)
        c.after(0)
        
        #c.coords(l1, 200,100,300,150)
        #c.coords(l2, 300,150,400,100)
    
b1=Button(text='Запуск', command = move)
b1.pack()
 
l1 = c.create_line(200,100,300,100)
l2 = c.create_line(300,100,400,100)
l3 = c.create_line(400,100,400,200)
l4 = c.create_line(400,200,400,300)
l5 = c.create_line(400,300,300,300)
l6 = c.create_line(300,300,200,300)
l7 = c.create_line(200,300,200,200)
l8 = c.create_line(200,200,200,100)
 
lcenter = c.create_line(200,100,300,200)
#x=300,y=200 координаты центра.
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Если совсем тупо - то рисовать квадрат восемью линиями, каждая от вершины до середины  стороны, а затем перерисовывать их, двигая один конец на 1 пиксель (условно в секунду 8 перерисовок - но проверить надо). Но с  `tkinter` не работаю, так что просто, как идея.

Comment: Ну я так и планировал, у меня проблема с перерисовкой линий, не могу сообразить как выстроить цикл. В моих попытках интерфейс виснет от бессконечного цикла.

Comment: Тогда проблема не с тем, что не можете "допереть, как движение организовать", а с тем, что не можете найти ошибку. Начните с того, что уберите рекуурсивный вызов `move` из функции. Не понимаю идею такую:-) После этого виснуть перестанет, а начнет по каждому нажатию кнопки одна линия двигаться. Далее продолжайте отладку и исправление. Вам надо, чтобы двигались все 8 линий, и чтобы на кнопку были завязаны только начало и конец движения. Думаю, не так много осталось исправить.

Comment: Спасибо, прогресс появился)
Только вопрос с циклом всё ещё открыть. Да, линии двигаются по щелкчу на кнопку, но они должны после нажатия беспрерывно двигаться(сжиматься-разжиматься). Пока что код такой:

Comment: добавьте лучше обновлённый код в вопрос второй частью. Он нечитаем в комментариях.

Comment: Я просто обновил весь код, вернее заменил на новый.

Comment: 1) код нерабочий. 'l1' какой-то появился. 2) Дальше не подскажу, надо `tkinter` знать. По логике, надо чтобы  'move' в цикле вызывался после первого нажатия кнопки и в цикле проверялось бы, нет ли нового нажатия. 3) не советую править вопросы, лучше вернуть как было, и открыть новый конкретный вопрос, чтобы вероятность ответа была выше. Перенес комментарий мой в ответ. Eсли он был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса) и/или принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева)

Comment: @Сергей цикл блокирует ui - надо переносить в тред, тред не может изменять уи - надо вешать отрисовку через root.after

Comment: @eri, спасибо, вы о том, что тут надо многопоточность вводить ("тред" - Thread?), так как у нас блокирующий ввод/вывод? (Как писал, не работал с `tkinter`, в таких случаях советы даю, чтобы подтолкнуть автора к размышлениям или к переформулированию вопроса тут, так что несколько туплю с пониманием вашего совета:-)).

Comment: Можно обойтись root.after таймером если нужно небольшое фпс. Двойная буферизация в треде и более частый Колбэк если нужен высокий фпс.

Answer (score 0):

Начните с того, что уберите рекуурсивный вызов `move` из функции.
После этого виснуть перестанет, а начнет по каждому нажатию кнопки одна линия двигаться. Далее продолжайте отладку и исправление. Вам надо, чтобы двигались все 8 линий, и чтобы на кнопку были завязаны только начало и конец движения. Думаю, не так много осталось исправить.